# Create column that groups by and analyze window of values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to group by ColA, and use a 2/3 day window in ColD to analyze those values to create 'NewCol'. Example and more information below:

```
 ColA     ColB         ColC     ColD
  B      2021-10-24    2         NA
  B      2021-10-25    4          2
  B      2021-10-26    500       496
  B      2021-10-27    100      -400
  B      2021-10-28    55       -45
  B      2021-10-29    600       545
  B      2021-10-30    8        -592 
  B      2021-10-31    4300     4292 
  B      2021-11-01    200     -4100
  H      2021-10-24    600       NA
  H      2021-10-25   10000     9400 
  H      2021-10-26    100     -9900 
  H      2021-10-27    300       200
  H      2021-10-28    2       -292
  H      2021-10-29    8         6
  H      2021-10-30    600      592
  H      2021-10-31    600      0
  H      2021-11-01    650      50
```

Goal is to create 'NewCol', which essentially looks at ColD and associated values in it's group (ColA) from 2&3 days ago - if the value is 200 or greater, flag it with 1. If ColD value < 200 then assign 0.

Example - group B on 2021-10-31 - will look at ColD values from 2&3 days ago - thus 545 and -45, respectively - since one of those values is >200, assign NewCol with 1.

```
 ColA     ColB         ColC     ColD     NewCol
  B      2021-10-24    2         NA        NA
  B      2021-10-25    4          2        NA
  B      2021-10-26    500       496       NA 
  B      2021-10-27    100      -400        0
  B      2021-10-28    55       -45         1
  B      2021-10-29    600       545        1
  B      2021-10-30    8        -592        0
  B      2021-10-31    4300     4292        1
  B      2021-11-01    200     -4100        1
  H      2021-10-24    600       NA        NA
  H      2021-10-25   10000     9400       NA
  H      2021-10-26    100     -9900       NA
  H      2021-10-27    300       200        1
  H      2021-10-28    2       -292         1
  H      2021-10-29    8         6          1
  H      2021-10-30    600      592         1
  H      2021-10-31    600      0           0
  H      2021-11-01    650      50          1
```

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: This might be a good place to start: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: @Ben.T yes all groups have the same consecutive dates, in ascending order. And yes I'm good with 0 instead of NaN.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the dates being consecutive and ordered per group, you can first compare the value in ColD to 200, and `groupby` the ColA. then use this grouped object with `shift` twice. Check if any (with `|`) of the two shifted values is `True` and cast to `int`

```
gr = df['ColD'].ge(200).groupby(df['ColA'])
df['newCol'] = (gr.shift(2)|gr.shift(3)).astype(int)
print(df)
#    ColA       ColB   ColC    ColD  newCol
# 0     B 2021-10-24      2     NaN       0
# 1     B 2021-10-25      4     2.0       0
# 2     B 2021-10-26    500   496.0       0
# 3     B 2021-10-27    100  -400.0       0
# 4     B 2021-10-28     55   -45.0       1
# 5     B 2021-10-29    600   545.0       1
# 6     B 2021-10-30      8  -592.0       0
# 7     B 2021-10-31   4300  4292.0       1
# 8     B 2021-11-01    200 -4100.0       1
# 9     H 2021-10-24    600     NaN       0
# 10    H 2021-10-25  10000  9400.0       0
# 11    H 2021-10-26    100 -9900.0       0
# 12    H 2021-10-27    300   200.0       1
# 13    H 2021-10-28      2  -292.0       1
# 14    H 2021-10-29      8     6.0       1
# 15    H 2021-10-30    600   592.0       1
# 16    H 2021-10-31    600     0.0       0
# 17    H 2021-11-01    650    50.0       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt=""" ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
B,2021-10-24,2,NA
B,2021-10-25,4,2
B,2021-10-26,500,496
B,2021-10-27,100,-400
B,2021-10-28,55,-45
B,2021-10-29,600,545
B,2021-10-30,8,-592 
B,2021-10-31,4300,4292 
B,2021-11-01,200,-4100
H,2021-10-24,600,NA
H,2021-10-25,0000,9400 
H,2021-10-26,100,-9900 
H,2021-10-27,300,200
H,2021-10-28,2,-292
H,2021-10-29,8,6
H,2021-10-30,600,592
H,2021-10-31,600,0
H,2021-11-01,650,50"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt),sep=',',parse_dates=['ColB'])
df['ColD_2']=df['ColD'].shift(2)
df['ColD_3']=df['ColD'].shift(3)
df['ColD_2_check']=np.where(df['ColD_2']>200,1,0)
df['ColD_3_check']=np.where(df['ColD_3']>200,1,0)
df['newCol']=df['ColD_2_check']|df['ColD_3_check']
df.drop(['ColD_2','ColD_3','ColD_2_check','ColD_3_check'],inplace=True,axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
ColA       ColB  ColC    ColD  newCol
0      B 2021-10-24     2     NaN       0
1      B 2021-10-25     4     2.0       0
2      B 2021-10-26   500   496.0       0
3      B 2021-10-27   100  -400.0       0
4      B 2021-10-28    55   -45.0       1
5      B 2021-10-29   600   545.0       1
6      B 2021-10-30     8  -592.0       0
7      B 2021-10-31  4300  4292.0       1
8      B 2021-11-01   200 -4100.0       1
9      H 2021-10-24   600     NaN       1
10     H 2021-10-25     0  9400.0       1
11     H 2021-10-26   100 -9900.0       0
12     H 2021-10-27   300   200.0       1
13     H 2021-10-28     2  -292.0       1
14     H 2021-10-29     8     6.0       0
15     H 2021-10-30   600   592.0       0
16     H 2021-10-31   600     0.0       0
17     H 2021-11-01   650    50.0       1
```

​